# ¿Como hacer que wildcard me devuelva solo los nombres de los archivos y no la url completa?

Tags: makefile

Estoy haciendo un archivos `makefiles` y tengo muchos archivos `*.cpp` dentro de la carpeta `./src`, me gustaría transformarlos en archivos objetos y colocarlo en la carpeta `./bin` para después compilarlo junto a `main.cpp`, este fue mi intento:

```make
SRC=./src
URL_BIN=./bin
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(URL_BIN)/%.o)
...
$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    @echo "Creando los archivos objectos.."
    ${CXX} -c -o $@ $<
```

El problema es que `wildcard` en vez de ponerme la url de la variable `$(URL_BIN)` + el nombre de los archivos en la variable `OBJS` le coloca el contenido de la variable `$(URL_BIN)` + la variable `$(SRC)` + el nombre del archivo, ocasionando que ocurra:

```bash
    g++ -c -o ./bin/./src/array.o ./src/array.cpp
    #Y lo que yo quiero que ocurra es:
    g++ -c -o ./bin/array.o ./src/array.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `wildcard` no está diseñada para hacer eso, pero los archivos `makefiles` cuentan con otras funciones para el tratado de texto que me puede ayudar a hacerlo:

- [`subst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-subst-1): Reemplaza una sub cadena:

```
#Con esto eliminamos la url del nombre del archivo dejando solo la extensión.
FILES=$(subst $(SRC)/,,$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp))
#Si quieres eliminar la extensión puedes hacer:
NAME_FILES=$(subst .cpp,,$(FILES))
#Y listo.
```

Lo que yo quería hacer se puede lograr de manera más fácil:

```
FILES_CPP=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
FILES_O=$(subst $(SRC),$(BIN),$(FILES_CPP:.cpp=.o))
#Nota si solo se quiere cambiar la extension se puede hacer de esta manera:
#$(FILES_CPP:.cpp=.o)
```

Y listo se obtiene la lista de todos los archivos .cpp y se transforma a una lista de archivos objetos en otro directorio.

Pero esa lista no se puede usar para compilar todo(o no he conseguido la forma de hacerlo), pero se puede aprovechar el signo `%` para hacerlo:

```
$(BIN)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    @echo Compilando archivo objeto{$@} ... usando {$<}
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Lecturas interesantes:

- [Text-Funtions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)
- [¿Cómo compilar todos los archivos CPP de una vez usando MakeFile?](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/como-compilar-todos-los-archivos-cpp-de-una-vez-usando-makefile/)